# Program for simple editing of MOV files

Tags: video, quicktime

I need a program for editing moves, specifically, only MOV files.
Only simple editing required - cropping, splitting, trimming, etc.
One requirement is that the program does not re-render the video file,
since such changes generally do not need this.

A good example would be QuickTime X trimming facility - you can trim 
a huge MOV file and it will save it in seconds, because it will not
render it again.

Answer (score 3):

[QuickTime Pro 7](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D3380Z/A) is still around, and can do quite a bit to .mov container files natively. You can select, copy and paste video, extract streams, etc. They removed a TON of features from QuickTime X in the interest of making it prettier and more "user-friendly."

Comment: I thought they just have not yet re-coded those features for 64 bit.  Nothing to do with making it pretty or user-friendly.  Nevertheless I still use QuickTime Pro 7, even if it is only for 32 bit architecture.

Comment: If they do indeed add all of the features of QuickTime 7 back into QuickTime X (and likewise with iMovie HD/'08 and Final Cut Pro 7/X), I will be _very pleased_, to say the least. I think the "user-friendly" argument is pretty solid however, especially in light of iMovie ditching the timeline and going with more visual-oriented clip selection methods, and how QTX is exactly like the iPhone's new movie editing interface.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use QT Pro 7, and when you save the file, don't save the file as a self-contained movie, save it as a reference movie. It will take a lot less time. Note that you will need to keep all the original files for the reference movie to work.